# Solr Geo based search

Tags: solr, lucene, geolocation, full-text-search, search-engine

We are starting to use Solr for a geographic based search engine. We provide a GPS location, and a radius and keyword. It is unclear to us if Solr first restricts the GPS location, then does a keyword search, or if it first does a keyword search and then reduces the results by filtering our results outside of the radius ... The first case would be preferable in our situation, as we have many data sets over all, but a small subset in a certain location, increasing the speed of the search.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all - Solr will not have this type of queries from the box. So, I see two ways - boost up fields with GPS location, so, matching with them will give you more boost, and results will get higher score, or probably write your own type of query, so you could measure the distance between needed location and location in docments you check for match.

Second way - actually - not related to Solr, but I've work with MongoDB a little, and it have geosearch feature. For more information check this (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/)

Comment: About the first way, wouldn't this also work? http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4

Comment: the document says: A common spatial requirement is to sort the search results by distance from a point such as the center of a map window. This works quite differently than Solr 3 spatial; you can't use geodist(). Instead, the spatial queries seen earlier are capable of returning a distance based score, which can then be sorted, used in relevancy boosting, and even returned in search results.

Comment: I can't seem to find a definitive answer on wither it does an Geo based search and then a keyword  search on those results, or the other way. And if both are possible, how to construct a query that does the two.